# Java Regex expression to append two strings

Tags: java, regex

I need to monitor a log file which will give me lines in the following way...

```
type=CWD<some text>cwd="something within double quotes"<some text><enter>
type=PATH<some text>name="something within double quotes"<some text>
```

Now I need a regex expression which will take those two variables in double quotes and append them to form a single string with a '/' in between
Eg: I need `<cwd_vale>/<name_value>`

`(\"\S*\")(\"\S*\")` will give two strings within double quotes to two groups
I want the way to append these strings. Help is so very welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

You can match both lines and use 2 capture groups using a negated character class `[^"]` as `\S` does not match the spaces between the double quotes.

Then concat the 2 capture groups with a `/`

```
cwd="([^"]*)".*\R.*?name="([^"]*)"
```

- `cwd="([^"]*)"` Capture the content between double quotes after `cwd="` in group 1
- `.*\R` Match the rest of the line and a newline
- `.*?name="([^"]*)"` Match as least as possible chars, match `name="` and capture the contents between the double quotes in group 2

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/dyeKtG) | [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0vrOMs/1)

```
String regex = "cwd=\"([^\"]*)\".*\\R.*?name=\"([^\"]*)\"";
String string = "type=CWD<some text>cwd=\"something within double quotes\"<some text><enter>\n"
    + "type=PATH<some text>name=\"something within double quotes\"<some text>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "/" + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output

```
something within double quotes/something within double quotes
```

---

For the values on a single line, and the second part can optionally start with `/`, you can optionally match the forward slash outside of the second group so that it would not be there when concatenating group 1 and group 2 having double `//`

```
String regex = "\\\"(\\S*)\\\".*?\\\"/?(\\S*)\\\"";
String string = "cwd=\"/root\" name=\"/msv_backup/archives/auditlogs\"";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "/" + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output

```
/root/msv_backup/archives/auditlogs
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/bK5nXA) | [REgex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cfb8Sy/1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Have tried the same but didnt help.... (\"(\S*)\").*(\"(\S*)\") is returning two strings in as Group 1: "<string in double quotes>" Group 2: <string in double quotes> as in https://regex101.com/r/mbPT0L/1/. Can u just help in appending them

Comment: @hiteshadabala I have added an example when the values are on the same line using `\S*` to match non whitespace chars only.

Comment: But i am not seeing it solve the problem. Can u start with telling how to append two strings or groups basically. We will surely look into edge cases like white spaces or enters next to this

Comment: @hiteshadabala Did you try the demo code and the demo link with the exact same example string? That is how you can concatenate the group values.

Comment: @hiteshadabala Else try using `String regex = "(?s)\\\"(\\S*)\\\".*?\\\"/?(\\S*)\\\"";` or `String regex = "(?s)\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\".*?\\\"/?([^\\\"]*)\\\"";`

Comment: I have tried the two expressions mentioned above and they only return two strings in two separate groups as in https://regex101.com/r/Aer9IZ/1 and https://regex101.com/r/9ieaIz/1 . Please help me to have one more group which will hold appended value of those two groups

Comment: @hiteshadabala You can not create a group with regex that holds both groups only when there are characters in between that you do not want in the group. What you can do is wrap the whole match in a group which "contains" group 2 and group 3 then, but you would still have to concatenate them.

Comment: I am not sure how can we concatenate two groups or strings basically using regex, that is where i am struck! @The fourth bird ,can u start helping from there please

Comment: @hiteshadabala The code examples in the answer show how you can get 2 capture group values from a regex that matches the given example string. This part `matcher.group(1)` gets the group value, and you can concatenate the values using `+` If you have example code that is not working, you can go to https://ideone.com/ and then select Java, add the code that you tried that is not working and **run** the code. The url will change to make it specific for this code, and you can share it here in the comments so I can see what is happening.

Comment: Now I got the point what I didn't explain and hence we missed being on same page @The fourth bird... I cannot use these in .java files. I am trying to write regex and do this operation in .xml file which will have java compiler in backend to one particular tag. It can only compile regex patterns. No more java code allowed. So whatever I want to get, I need to get it to one group using regex expressions alone. Please help me in this Regex compiler https://regex101.com/r/6VnSx5/1/